# Pearson's correlation for non-linear data

Tags: regression, correlation, pearson-r, nonlinear

It's known that Pearson's correlation is able to measure trends for an observed sample $y$ and a possible linear relationship with a simulated data $y^{(s)}$, being $+1$ if $y^{(s)} = a + by$ and $b >0$.

But, does it matter the shape of the observed data $y$? For instance, if I have $y = f(x) = x^2$, would it make any effect for Pearson's correlation? My intuition says no, but I want to find a more reliable source.

Comment: Are you alluding to the canonical example of zero correlation but a clear relationship: $E[X] = 0$, density of $X$ is symmetric, and $Y = X^2$? Then $Corr(X,Y) = 0$ but there is an entirely deterministic relationship.

Comment: I think my question is much simpler than that. Does the characteristics of the observed sample matter for the Pearson? Does it have to obey any sort of characteristics?

Comment: That has a simple mathematical answer, obtainable from any formula for the correlation: it is defined provided both variables have nonzero variance.

Comment: *"Does the characteristics of the observed sample matter for the Pearson?"* what does that term 'matter' actually mean in this context?. You can compute a Pearson correlation for any set of paired numbers, whether it is a linear relationship or not, so I would say that it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pearson's correlation coefficient is a measure of strength of **linear relationship** between the variable. So, it may provide false results for non-linear relationship.

Read a more detailed answer on [*Correlation and dependence*](https://qr.ae/pNKmLP)

Comment: I would say something like, "It may not pickup any aspect of a non-linear relationship." For example, if $X \sim N(0, 1)$ and $Y = X^2$, then $Corr(X,Y)=0$. That result is *true*! Saying it provides "false results" in this case isn't quite right.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on [Dr Nisha Arora's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/220100/216706), the following provides a method to compute meaningful Pearson linear correlation coefficient (PLCC) in such cases.

Suppose, you have
$$y=f(x)=x^2$$
Take log on both sides
$$log(y) = 2 \ log(x)$$
Now have a linear relationship. Find Pearson's Correlation Coefficient now. Read [this](https://qr.ae/TUhdoc)  answer for more details.

Comment: nonlinear transformations e.g. *log-transformation* will generally affect the correlation between 2 pairs. [Reference](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/403449/240550)

Comment: @Mario, of course. You're right. I've updated my answer. To further clarify, we are banking on that. Pearson correlation (PLCC) is defined for linear dependencies. For non-linear dependencies, PLCC does not make much sense. So, we convert our non-linear relationship to a linear one and then compute PLCC. This is also common in the [literature](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/5404314).